# What's the correct way to install Drupal with Composer if I want to work on core issues?

Tags: composer

I want to install a local Drupal site in such a way that Drupal core is a git repository so I can work on patches.

Just doing a git clone doesn't work, because I also need tools such as Drush, and installing those in a git clone of core changes the `composer.json` file that belongs to core.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do core development with composer-based install?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274750/how-to-do-core-development-with-composer-based-install)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there really is a correct, or best way.  All of the core devs I have interacted with have their own setup that works best for them.

My general setup is

- directory per remote branch: right now I have drupal-8.8.x, drupal 8.9.x, and drupal 9.0.x
- git branch for each patch that is in the issue-comment form: 3113284-02, 3113284-04)

I do this because I have a bunch of shell scripts for installing, cleaning, diffing, generating patches, running tests, etc.  All of these scripts get ignored.

As far as drush goes, I keep a global install and checkout a tag periodically.  I then have a [.envrc](https://direnv.net/) in each branch directory to $PATH everything correctly.  This prevents changes to composer.json.

However, there are some things you can try. A while ago, running tests locally with certain PHP versions meant updating phpunit via a post-composer script.  You then had to restore composer.json and composer.lock before running a `git diff ...` to generate a patch/interdiff.  You can do the something similar with drush:

- git pull origin/8.8.x
- composer require drush/drush:^10
- git checkout composer.json composer.lock

The above approach is on my short-list for updates to my scripts.

Comment: How do you install Drupal in the first place -- is it just a git clone that you then run `composer install` on?

Comment: @joachim Yeah, `git clone`, checkout the branch I want, then `composer install`.  You want a git clone of the official repo so that the git indexes matches up when you have tricky applies/rerolls.

Comment: And then you're forever having to muck about with the composer.lock file when you want to make patches, aren't you?

Comment: @joachim No, if I mess with composer.json or composer.lock, I just restore it to `origin` afterwards. If I don't, then the lockfile never changes.  I have never found it to be a hassle.  The core dependencies are mostly stable; they tend to change near a release if bumping the Symfony point releases change.  I worked on at least five issues this weekend, and don't think I needed to worry about composer once.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by installing Drush separately (I'm still using Drush 8), then I can run Drush commands on installs of Drupal that are downloaded with git.

Comment: That's not sustainable though -- Drush 8 is deprecated surely?

Comment: Drush 8 kinda needs to live as long as Drupal 7 does, because Drush 9+ only work with Drupal 8+.

Comment: Also, what about things like Devel module?

Comment: Every other module I work on (I have a few hundred downloaded locally) is downloaded manually using git - you don't need composer to do that.

Comment: That's only viable for now because they don't have their own composer dependencies!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the `preferred-install` **source** like I [documented for contrib modules](https://build2be.com/content/working-drupal-module-using-composer) which fits my needs.

```
composer create-project --no-install drupal/recommended-project:8.8.x-dev se-291135
cd se-291135/
```

This results in a require of **^8.8** (like 8.8.2) so we need to edit composer.json and change all those occurrences into **8.8.x-dev** and add the `preferred-install`

```
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "drupal/core": "source",
            "*": "dist"
        },
        ...
```

Not sure why I had to remove the lock file :-/

```
rm composer.lock
```

Installing with these settings we get a `drupal/code` in **web/core** with a detached head. Fix that and we are almost done.

```
composer install
cd web/core
git checkout origin/8.8.x
```

To make sure our patches matches drupal a `git diff` alias would help like

```
alias corediff='git diff --src-prefix=a/core/ --dst-prefix=b/core/'
```

Comment: How does Composer react to changing the git checkout of core? Won't it try to revert that anytime you do a `composer update` or `composer install`? How do you add Drush?